# Rails before_action for ActionMailer that would use mailer arguments

Tags: ruby, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I have a mailer that sends different emails, but is expected to be called with the same parameters. I want to process those parameters for all mailer actions. So, calling a `before_action` that would read the parameters sent to the mailer method

```
/mailers/my_mailer.rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
    before_filter do |c|
      # c.prepare_mail # Will fail, because I need to pass `same_param` arguments
      # # I want to send the original arguments
      # c.prepare_mail(same_param) # How do I get `same_param` here ?
    end

    def action1(same_param)
      # email view is going to use @to, @from, @context    
      method_only_specific_to_action1
    end

    def action2(same_param)
      # email view is going to use @to, @from, @context
      method_only_specific_to_action2
    end

    private
      def prepare_mail(same_params)
        @to = same_params.recipient
        @from = same_params.initiator
        @context = same_params.context
      end
    end
```

Then in my controller/service I do somewhere

```
MyMailer.actionx(*mailer_params).deliver_now
```

How can I access the `same_param` arguments list inside the `before_action` block ?

EDIT :

I want to refactor from

```
/mailers/my_mailer.rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer

    def action1(same_param)
      @to = same_params.recipient
      @from = same_params.initiator
      @context = same_params.context   
      method_only_specific_to_action1
    end

    def action2(same_param)
      @to = same_params.recipient
      @from = same_params.initiator
      @context = same_params.context   
      method_only_specific_to_action2
    end

    def actionx
      ... 
    end
  end
```

And this refactoring

```
/mailers/my_mailer.rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer

    def action1(same_param)
      prepare_mail(same_params)   
      method_only_specific_to_action1
    end

    def action2(same_param)
      prepare_mail(same_params)   
      method_only_specific_to_action2
    end

    def actionx
      ... 
    end

    private
      def prepare_mail(same_params)
        @to = same_params.recipient
        @from = same_params.initiator
        @context = same_params.context
      end
    end
```

Feels non-optimal (`prepare_mail(same_params)` duplicated in every action)

Hence what was suggested above

Comment: just a thought - have you thought of just using net::STMP directly to send emails  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html. It will be more customizable than Action Mailer.

Comment: From a software engineering point of view, ActionMailer is an adapter, and you can configure several email delivery methods (I'm currently using 3-4), I'm afraid SMTP isn't all there is in the world, so I want to use ActionMailer.

Comment: I think you are moving logic part from the controller into the layer. Its best to add a service layer/model class in between the mailer class and controller to achieve this rather than overriding the default mailer to achieve what you want.

Comment: @spickermann Sorry forgot the inheritance, adding it now. You can consider `ApplicationMailer` is like `ActionMailer::Base`. In my previous comment I was just explaining I'm not just sending mails directly via SMTP but also configuring to use `:file`, `:cache`, `:letter_opener`, etc delivery adapters which are wrapped nicely by ActionMailer

Comment: @sairam I disagree, you can see in the `prepare_mail` I am just setting instance variables that will be directly used in an ActionMailer's view. I would have to pass too many parameters otherwise

Comment: @spickermann No not at all sorry if the question isn't clear, but the previous comment mentionned completely cutting off ActionMailer. I just want to understand if in my `before_action` filter I can do something like
`c.prepare_mail(*arguments_sent_to_mailer_action)`. I just edited, hope it's clearer

Comment: `before_action` is defined in `AbstractController::Callbacks`. This method doesn't exist in the context of a Mailer. If you really want to use callbacks in the context of an Mailer than you need to implement the logic to use them. You might want to have a look into [`ActiveSupport::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html).

Comment: @spickermann I'm sorry, but `Callbacks in Action Mailer are implemented using AbstractController::Callbacks` (at least in Rails 4-5, yes I know it's weird they didn't refactor that name) and `before_action` DOES work. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: You problem seems to be solved by **parameterized mailers** that are part of Rails 5.1 (see [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27825))

Comment: Hey @spickermann that sounds cool ! Please add an answer with that when it is released, I'll definitely use it :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ActionMailer uses the `AbstractController::Callbacks` module. I tried it and it seems to work for me.

The code

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def process_action(*args)
    # process the args here
    puts args
    super
  end

  def some_mail(*args)
  end
end

MyMailer.some_mail(1, 2) #=> prints ['some_mail', 1, 2]
```

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks.html#method-i-process_action)

---

UPDATE

If you're using Rails 5.1, you can have a look at [ActionMailer::Parameterized](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized.html)

Comment: how would you do this using before_action? I tried, but there were no args

Comment: I don't know neither. Actually if you're using Rails 5.1, you can have a look at [ActionMailer::Parameterized](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized.html)

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized.html is actually quite nice and probably where things are going, but it actually broke most existing tests and at the time of writing, it is actually not supported very well with RSpec and will involve quite a bit of code rewriting. We've tried to use this in different mailers, but at the time of writing, it wasn't as easy to use as `process_action`

Comment: @pixelearth you could assign this to an instance variable ex `@mailer_arguments = args`, then in the before action access @mailer_arguments and use them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Solution1:

I would suggest you use this if you do not care about the format

```
MyMailer.generic("actionx", *mailer_params).deliver_now

def generic(actiontype, *mailer_params)
  # custom logic goes here to construct the to, from, etc.,
  # new_options from custom logic
  self.send(actiontype, new_options)
end
```

> alternative solution below using method_missing from the parent controller

Its not right to put your logic there, but if you still want to do it, you can use the method_missing to put your logic there and skip the action1 and action2 methods.

Original method_missing from action_mailer which can be used as a reference:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  if action_methods.include?(method_name.to_s)
    MessageDelivery.new(self, method_name, *args)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c8a18aaf44a84f1ef0df007aa3f8446752dc327d/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L561-L567

Comment: The problem is there's a lot of `not-really logic` that consists in filling the email headers (and they are the same for every action), but each individual mailer_action remains specific and I might want to do extra stuff in there (like attaching a specific file, etc.)

Comment: see the first solution. self.send(actiontype, options)

Comment: Oh right that actually makes sense ! Sorry didn't realize what it was doing at first.

Comment: @Sairam, did you actually try your first suggestion?  It's appealing, but under rails 4.2, I get `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template my_mailer/generic with "mailer"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sairam's answer I though of the following but that feels a bit weird, can it not be done with `before_action` callback ??

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer

    # Simulation of before_action callback that would support passing the *args to the callback method
    def self.method_missing(method_name, *args)
      method_name = :"#{method_name.to_s}_headers_prefilled"
      if action_methods.include?(method_name)
        mailer = MyMailer.generic(*args) # The before_action callback that passes *args
        mailer.send(method_name, *args) # The action itself
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def generic(*mailer_params)
      # custom logic goes here to construct the headers to, from, etc.,
    end

    def action1_headers_prefilled(mailer_params)
      # Logic only relevant for action1
    end
```

Also I lose all the cool stuff from before_action (passing an `only` or `except` array, etc.)