# Are arguments passed into UserMailer available to before_actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to assign the same set of instance variables for multiple emails based on the argument passed into mailer. Something like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  before_action -> { set_defaults(order) }, only: [:email1, :email2]

  def email1(order)
    ...
  end

  def email2(order)
    ...
  end

  private
    set_defaults(order)
      @order = order
      @customer = order.customer
      @price = order.price
    end
end
```

I see that you can pass `params`, `strings`, and the like to before_actions in controllers: [Rails 4 before_action, pass parameters to invoked method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260288/rails-4-before-action-pass-parameters-to-invoked-method)

And it looks like I can use `process_action` as workaround: [Rails before_action for ActionMailer that would use mailer arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634619/rails-before-action-for-actionmailer-that-would-use-mailer-arguments)

But is there a way to access arguments? Are they out of scope? Help.

Comment: You can access them, and no they aren't?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I mean specifically within the before_action? When I test in the rails console, it throws an error.

Comment: Tracy (and why can't I @ some people here and others I can?) . You just need to use the `process_action` method as described in your second link.

Comment: I think you can’t @ the asker because all comments are automatically sent to the asker and do not require tagging (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: SO is so smart, thanks that explains it indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ?

```
DO_ME_BEFORE = [:email1, :email2]

def process_action(*args)
    return super unless DO_ME_BEFORE.include?(args[0].to_sym)
    @order = args[1]
    @customer = @order.customer
    @price = @order.price
    super
end
```

Edit:
I don't think you can hook exactly in the same way as with `before_action`, but you can simulate it, since your `args[0]` will be the name of the method. If you write the array of allowed methods as strings, you don't need to call `.to_sym` on `args[0]` on the `.include?()`

Comment: I only want to process arguments for some actions and not all of them. Is there a way to do that?